# Removing outliers can not runt cor.test()

Tags: r

I am extracting outliers from a single column of a dataset. Then I am attempting to run `cor.test()` on that column plus another column.  I am getting error: `Error in cor.test.default(dep_delay_noout, distance) :  'x' and 'y' must have the same length`  I assume this is because removing the outliers from one column caused it to be a different length vector than the other column, but am not sure what to do about it. I have tried mutating the dataset by adding a new column that lacked outliers, but unfortunately ran into the same problem.  Does anybody know what to do?  Below is my code.

```
dep_delay<-flights$dep_delay

dep_delay_upper<-quantile(dep_delay,0.997,na.rm=TRUE)
dep_delay_lower<-quantile(dep_delay,0.003,na.rm=TRUE)

dep_delay_out<-which(dep_delay>dep_delay_upper|dep_delay<dep_delay_lower)

dep_delay_noout<-dep_delay[-dep_delay_out]

distance<-flights$distance
cor.test(dep_delay_noout,distance)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. In `cor.test` you also want to subset `distance`. Additionally, for the preprocessing you could use a `quantile` vector of length 2 and `mapply` to do the comparison in one step―just to write it more concise, actually your code is fine.

```
data('flights', package='nycflights13')

nna <- !is.na(flights$dep_delay)

(q <- quantile(flights$dep_delay[nna], c(0.003, 0.997)))
 # 0.3% 99.7% 
 #  -14   270 

nout <- rowSums(mapply(\(f, q) f(flights$dep_delay[nna], q), c(`>`, `<`), q)) == 2

with(flights, cor.test(dep_delay[nout], distance[nout]))
# Pearson's product-moment correlation
# 
# data:  dep_delay[no_out] and distance[no_out]
# t = -12.409, df = 326171, p-value < 2.2e-16
# alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  -0.02515247 -0.01829207
# sample estimates:
#         cor 
# -0.02172252
```

Comment: I tried subsetting distance using this code: `cor_results=cor.test(dep_delay_noout,distance) cor_results%>%
 cor_select(distance)

Comment: Sorry, I got cut off in my original comment. I tried subsetting distance using this code: `cor_results=cor.test(dep_delay_noout,distance) cor_results%>% cor_select(distance)`  The instructions I used for subsetting were found at this link [link]https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/rstatix/reference/cor_select.html.  I am still getting the same error.  I like your method better, but I would like to understand both ways.  Can you show me why my subset is wrong?

Comment: @jakdar It's this logic: `x <- 1:100; y <- 100:1; nout <- 1:50; cor.test(x[nout], y[nout]); cor.test(x[nout], y)`, you need a `distance_nout`, where the same observations are removed.